# Add sticky footer to fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a footer to my fragment layouts.  What I have worked fine before I converted everything to fragments, now the footer shows above the listing fragment, instead of below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>
    <!-- Footer -->     
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/footer" 
            android:background="#919191"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            style="@style/Footer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         />
    <!-- Footer -->

    <fragment android:name="com.app.ListingFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentListing"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
     />

 </LinearLayout>

<style name="Footer">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">#919191</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinearLayout doesn't understand "layout_alignParentBottom" and "layout_above". You should remove them and just swap TextView with the fragment.

"layout_alignParentBottom" and "layout_above" only work with views that are embedded in RelativeLayouts.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, my pre-fragment layouts were RelativeLayouts.